# Publish html/js project to github page

Tags: github-pages

I have a simple javascript projet created using npm.  The source code is in a public github repository.

Here is the content of the repository

```
my-project
  src
    index.html
    app.js
  package.json
  README.md
```

In my local environment I run it using lite-server by executing npm run dev.

I create gh-pages branch from my main branch, my code was automatically deployed after but when I visit the page it show the content of the README.md file.

How can I point to my index.html page instead so that my simple website is rendered ?

Do I have to absolutely move my index.html to the root directory ?  Or is there other way without changing my project folder structre ?

=============== MY SOLUTION ===============

I just had to copy index.html and app.js at the root of the branch gh-pages.

Answer (score 0):

You can only choose the root folder or `/docs` from repo settings.

https://docs.github.com/en/pages/getting-started-with-github-pages/configuring-a-publishing-source-for-your-github-pages-site

Comment: As far as I understand it only propose the root directory or the docs directory and there is no possibility to choose another directory

Comment: You're right, I do not think there is any other way to do it. Maybe consider vercel or netlify?